# How to validate an array including certain type of object with hapi/joi framework in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation, hapi.js

My object is like:

```
"resources":[
     {
        "date": "2019-04-17",
        "values":[
            {"Customer":"C_name"},
            {"Environment":66.5},
            {"Other": {"goods": "feature", "present": 12}
     }
]
```

I want to know how to validate values, I mean the values array should contain at least one customer object, an Environment object, and Other Objects. How to use @hapi/joi framework to validate this array and it should contain different objects in this array?

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of `map`, `every` and `some`:

```js
const resources = [{
  "date": "2019-04-17",
  "values": [{
      "Customer": "C_name"
    },
    {
      "Environment": 66.5
    },
    {
      "Other": {
        "goods": "feature",
        "present": 12
      }
    }
  ]
}]

function valid(arr) {
  return arr
    .map(x => x.values)
    .every(y =>
      y.some(z => z.hasOwnProperty("Customer"))
      && y.some(z => z.hasOwnProperty("Environment")) 
      && y.some(z => z.hasOwnProperty("Other"))
    )
}

console.log(valid(resources));
```